# How to calculate the follow sets of boolean expression

Tags: compiler-construction

The grammar is like below:

```
bexpr -> bexpr or bterm | bterm
bterm -> bterm and bfactor | bfactor
bfactor -> not bfactor | ( bexpr ) | true | false
```

and I have already removed left recursion

```
bexpr -> bterm bexpr'
bexpr' -> or bterm bexpr' | ε
bterm -> bfactor bterm'
bterm' -> and bfactor bterm' | ε
bfactor -> not bfactor | (bexpr) | true | false
```

I've calculated the first sets

```
first(bexpr) = first(bterm) = first(bfactor) = [not, (, true, false]
first(bexpr') = [or, ε]
first(bterm') = [and, ε]
```

I thought the follow sets of bterm and bfactor are

```
follow(bterm)=first(bexpr')\epsilon+follow(bexpr)=[or]+[$,)]=[or,$,)]
follow(bfactor)=first(bterm')\epsilon+follow(bterm)=[and]+[or,$,)]=[and, or, $, )]
```

but the reference answer says

```
follow(bterm) = [or, $]
follow(bfactor) = [and, $]
```

Why am I wrong?

Comment: Is your task to compute FIRST and FOLLOW for the original grammar, or for the one with left recursion eliminated? They're not the same.

Comment: @Michael Dyck for the one with left recursion eliminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reference answer is incorrect. For example, consider the derivation:

```
bexpr
-> bterm bexpr'
-> bterm
-> bfactor bterm'
-> bfactor
-> ( bexpr )
-> ( bterm bexpr' )
-> ( bterm )
-> ( bfactor bterm' )
-> ( bfactor )
```

This shows that you can derive sentential forms in which both `bterm` and `bfactor` are immediately followed by `)`. Thus, according to the definition of `FOLLOW`, `)` must be in both `FOLLOW(bterm)` and `FOLLOW(bfactor)` (which is true in your answer but not the reference answer).

The only other discrepancy is that your answer has `or` in `FOLLOW(bfactor)` and the reference answer doesn't. You can show it should be there by finding a derivation in which `bfactor` is immediately followed by `or`, which shouldn't be too hard.

---

More simply, observe just the derivation

```
bterm
-> bfactor bterm'
-> bfactor
```

Thus, in sentential forms, a `bfactor` can appear anywhere that a `bterm` appears, and so the follow-set for `bfactor` must include all the symbols in the follow-set for `bterm`. This is the case in your answer but not in the reference answer.